# Laravel 4: Cookie not setting?

Tags: cookies, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to set a cookie in laravel like:

```
    $cookie = Cookie::forever('knownWords', serialize($words));
                return Response::json(array('status' => "FAIL", 
                    "msg" => "Info stored in cookie!"))->headers->setCookie($cookie);
```

And then later in a different route, access it, and send it as a json response as such:

```
   $words = array();
        if(Cookie::has('knownWords')){
            $words = unserialize(Cookie::get('knownWords'))
        }
        return Response::json(array('status' => "FAIL", 
            "msg" => "Not logged in! Cookie info attached.",
            "data" => $words));
```

I'm not getting any errors, but I can confirm it's not goign into the Cookie::has() if statement. Any idea guys? I'm pretty new to cookies! I'm using localhost and chrome if you need to know!

EDIT: I'm calling these routes via AJAX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently i just needed to use composer to update Laravel. Now it works. :D

Answer (score -2):

Try using `withCookie()`. I mean, change this:

```
return Response::json(array(
    "status" => "FAIL", 
    "msg" => "Info stored in cookie!"
))->headers->setCookie($cookie);
```

for this:

```
return Response::json(array(
    "status" => "FAIL", 
    "msg" => "Info stored in cookie!"
))->withCookie($cookie);
```

---

This is what I have so far, and working:

```
<?php // routes.php

Route::get('/', function() {
    return View::make('index');
});

Route::get('set', function()
{
    $words = ['foo', 'bar'];
    $cookie = Cookie::forever('knownWords', serialize($words));
    return Response::json(array('status' => "FAIL", "msg" => "Info stored in cookie!"))->withCookie($cookie);
});

Route::get('see', function()
{
    $words = array();

    if(Cookie::has('knownWords')){
        $words = unserialize(Cookie::get('knownWords'));
    }

    return Response::json(array('status' => "FAIL", 
        "msg" => "Not logged in! Cookie info attached.",
        "data" => $words));  
});
```

Then, the view (simple html with an AJAX call):

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: '{{ URL::to("set") }}',
                success: function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: tried that already, apparently Response::json() doesn't work like the rest of the response stuff. the ->headers->setCookie() is what I found when looking for solutions, but that doesn't seem to work either. withCookie complains that it's a undefined method.

Comment: Well, it's working for me. And I've just copypasted your code and added `$words = ['foo', 'bar'];` before it.

Comment: Are you calling it via ajax?

Comment: Nope, but you didn't specify that in your question ;)

Comment: I'll go specify that now. :P Could you try it and tell me if it works?

Comment: Yes, it's working too. By the way, you have a missing `;` inside your `if` statement. Maybe that's causing a server error?

Comment: the missing ; is cause I deleted an error_log() before posting this, must have hit backspace one too many times. Anyways, I wonder what this could be then. Any other ideas or stuff for me to try?

Comment: Maybe try with a fresh Laravel install and see what happens. I'll add full code to the answer anyway.

Comment: your Response::json() works with withCookie()? Did you try it with the ->headers->setCookie()?